# Getting Unsuported Client TLS 1.1 error

Tags: javascript, integration, soap, tls

We have integration between .net web application and Salesforce.

In Salesforce from Certificate Object we select list of records and we click on the "Generate Certificate Button" the Button is Java Script button which Executes the .net Certificate Generation aspx page. And it will show "The certificate is generated successfully and Stored in Sharepoint"

However for Few User they are getting this error.

"An error occured: UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.
Sorry for inconvenience caused. Please contact your administrator."

Please find the image below.
[image]

This error is occurring on for users in Australia ,Users in INDIA are having no issue at all

Please find the Screen shot what Users in India are getting.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because Salesforce has begun the phased disablement of the TLS 1.0 encryption protocol. The impact of the TLS 1.0 disablement will vary by org, and depends on the ways in which your users connect to the Salesforce service. Upgrade to TLS version 1.1 now to ensure uninterrupted access to all of your Salesforce orgs.

Salesforce will be disabling TLS 1.0 according to the schedule below so to fix your issue upgrade TLS version to 1.1

[image]

Resources for a smooth transition to TLS 1.1 or higher:

- Issue article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232847&type=1
- [TLS 1.0 Disablement Readiness Checklist (PDF)](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150M000003KgGkQAK) for best practices on how to prepare for this change
- [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67504/discussion-between-himanshu-and-samuel-robert).